# INSERT SELECT ON DUPLICATE not updating

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, on-duplicate-key

**Short**

1. I want to `SUM` a column in `TABLE_A` based on `CRITERIA X` and insert into `TABLE_B.total_x`
2. I want to `SUM` a column in `TABLE_A` based on `CRITERIA Y` and insert into `TABLE_B.total_y`
3. *Problem*: Step 2 does not update `TABLE_B.total_y`

**LONG**

TABLE_A: Data

```
| year | month | type | total |
---------------------------------------
| 2013 | 11    | down | 100   |
| 2013 | 11    | down | 50    |
| 2013 | 11    | up   | 60    |
| 2013 | 10    | down | 200   |
| 2013 | 10    | up   | 15    |
| 2013 | 10    | up   | 9     |
```

TABLE_B: structure

```
CREATE TABLE `TABLE_B` (
    `year` INT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `month` INT(2) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `total_x` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `total_y` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX `unique` (`year`, `month`)
)
```

SQL: CRITERIA_X

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_B (
 `year`, `month`, `total_x`
)
SELECT 
  t.`year`, t.`month`,
  SUM(t.`total`) as total_x
FROM TABLE_A t
WHERE
  t.`type` = 'down'
GROUP BY
  t.`year`, t.`month`
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  `total_x` = total_x
;
```

SQL: CRITERIA_Y

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_B (
 `year`, `month`, `total_y`
)
SELECT 
  t.`year`, t.`month`,
  SUM(t.`total`) as total_y
FROM TABLE_A t
WHERE
  t.`type` = 'up'
GROUP BY
  t.`year`, t.`month`
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  `total_y` = total_y
;
```

The second SQL (CRITERIA_Y) does not update `total_y` as expected. **WHY?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it another way

```
insert into TABLE_B (year, month, total_x, total_y)
select year, month
     , sum (case [type] when 'down' then [total] else 0 end) [total_x]
     , sum (case [type] when 'up' then [total] else 0 end) [total_y]
from TABLE_A
group by [year], [month]
```

Or using two subqueries way would be

```
insert into TABLE_B (year, month, total_x, total_y)
select coalesce(t1.year, t2.year) year
     , coalesce(t1.month, t2.month) month
     , t1.total_x total_x
     , t2.total_y total_y
from (select year, month, sum(total) total_x
         from TABLE_A where [type]='down') t1 
full outer join
     (select year, month, sum(total) total_y
         from TABLE_A where [type]='up') t2
     on t1.year = t2.year and t1.month = t2.month
```

Or using union

```
insert into TABLE_B (year, month, total_x, total_y)
select year, month, sum(total_x), sum(total_y)
from ( 
   select year, month, sum(total) total_x, 0 total_y
   from TABLE_A where [type]='down'
   group by year, month
   union
   select year, month, 0 total_x, sum(total) total_y
   from TABLE_A where [type]='up'
   group by year, month) t
group by year, month
```

Reading specs on INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, I noticed this:

> If ... matches several rows, only one row is updated. In general, you should try to avoid using an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause on tables with multiple unique indexes.

So syntax with composite key is kind of cumbersome, and I personally would avoid using it.

Comment: I've never done SUM in that way before. Let me see if it works

Comment: Perfect. This is similar to what I had in mind to do, but didn't know how to do. Thanks

Comment: If you can explain it, I would still be interested in why the way I've done it doesn't work...

Comment: Sub-query looks way cumbersome. Union seems like the better way to go for general purpose. But the SUM (case) seems to be like a really good shortcut way to do it. I might use it more often. Thanks for adding more explanations to the answer.